# What is the purpose of wrapping fish with aluminum foil?

Tags: oven, fish, aluminum-foil

I was wondering what would be the difference if we wrap or don't wrap the fish with aluminum foil when baking. And also covering it with salt - how much of a difference would it make?

Comment: @Robert was being sarcastic.  There are countless ways to cook fish.  Most of them do not use aluminum foil or a pile of salt.  So, you are going to have to be more specific.  Is there a particular recipe you are curious about?  If so, it is helpful here to include it.  That way folks can weigh in on the purpose of the foil and/or the salt.

Comment: No not a particular receipt, but generally speaking,  just wanted to know, when would we wrap and when it is not necessary

Comment: Are you baking, grilling, broiling, poaching, or something else?

Comment: Does putting in an electric oven have so many different names?

Comment: I've assumed you mean baking (given the "oven" tag - it never actually said in the question), and tried to clarify your question. Please edit further if it's not what you meant!

Answer (score 4):

Cooking fish or other items in paper, "en papillote" is a technique used to lock in moisture and basically steam the fish in its own moisture and any aromatics you add.  Using foil is often done in the same way and to remove the fish or other items from more direct drying and scorching effects of heat while cooking, much as you might use foil on poultry breast to try to prevent burning while getting the slower cooking thigh up to temp.

If by covering with salt, you mean directly to the fish or other item and either using a bed of salt or burying them in it, one point is to flavor of course, but also to draw out some moisture.  Both in this case, and if the item has been wrapped so the salt does not actually contact the food, the idea I have always learned is to even out the temperature and turn it into more of an indirect heating.  The goal in this case is to try to get to temperature again without scorching or open drying of the item and get a more even heating in theory.